# Why doesn't pug take this script tag as closed?

Tags: pug, webstorm

I'm trying to "translate" an HTML file to Pug, and currently I have this:

```
extends layout
   block content
      script.
          System.import('main.js').catch(function (err) {
              console.error(err);
          });
```

The thing is, if I press enter at the end of the file, instead of taking the script tag as closed and taking me back to the previous indent level, WebStorm is acting as if I'm still writing code inside the script tag.

How can I force close the tag, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: WebStorm can't know if this is the end of your script block, or more code lines are to be added. If you like moving to previous level, hit Backspace after Enter (make sure that  'Backspace | Unindent' is set to 'To nearest indent position' in Preferences | Editor | General | Smart keys)